# Run Task in Gradle Plugin after check

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I've written a Gradle Plugin in Groovy under `buildSrc` as:

```
package test

import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class SamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        println "This line prints" //Just for Configuration. This prints
        def sample = project.tasks.create("sample") {
            doLast {
                println "This line does not print" 
            }
        }
        project.configure(project) {
            sample.mustRunAfter('check')
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I'm trying to run the `sample` task at the end of my `build`, so I have it run after `check`

I now try to call it in my projects `build.gradle` file that looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin:'application'
apply plugin: test.SamplePlugin

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = "test.Widget"
```

Unfortunately, I don't see that it runs i.e. the code in the `doLast` does not appear in the output, but the configuration code does:

```
:buildSrc:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileGroovy
:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:classes
:buildSrc:jar
:buildSrc:assemble
:buildSrc:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:test NO-SOURCE
:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE
:buildSrc:build
This line prints
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:startScripts UP-TO-DATE
:distTar UP-TO-DATE
:distZip UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test NO-SOURCE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date
```

I'd be grateful for any help or pointers

**Edit:** As **M.Ricciuti** commented below *order matters*, so I have moved the `test.SamplePlugin` after the plugin `java`. Otherwise, please follow **lu.koerfer**s solution of using the `pluginManager`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your plugin you are creating a new task 'sample' and set a constraint "sample must run after check":  but this does not include the sample task in the task graph . It just says: "if sample and check tasks are both executed , then check task must be executed first". So if you just execute 'gradle build', this will not trigger execution of task "sample".

Try to execute directly "gradle sample" : you will see it will trigger its execution, and make the execution of "check" task  first in respect of the contraint you have defined in plugin.

If you want to make "sample" task execute each time you execute "build" task, then just set a "dependsOn" constraint between "build" and "sample" tasks, in your plugin:

```
class SamplePlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    @Override
    void apply(Project project) {
        println "This line prints" //Just for Configuration. This prints
        def sample = project.tasks.create("sample") {
            doLast {
                println "This line does not print"
            }
        }
        project.configure(project) {
            sample.mustRunAfter('check')
            project.getTasks().findByName('build').dependsOn(sample) // <== set this contraint

        }
    }
}
```

*EDIT* : to avoid having to rely on plugin apply order, the task dependency declaration could be wrapped in a "afterEvaluate"  block:

```
void apply(Project project) {
        // task 'sample' def ...
        // ... 

        project.configure(project) {
            project.afterEvaluate {
                sample.mustRunAfter('check')
                project.getTasks().findByName('build').dependsOn(sample)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Well, you would still need the `mustRunAfter` statement, otherwise `sample` may run just at the start.

Comment: Also, if only `check` is run and not the full `build`, `sample` will not run.

Comment: you are right, but the main point of my answer was to explain why `sample` task was not executed with his current script, and give him solution based on `dependsOn` API to implement his requirement correctly. It's not clear what he really wants to achieve ( make `sample` task run after `build` task or after `check` task?) but he can implement the way he wants. You proposed solution based on `finalizedBy()` which I think is good too (I upvoted :) ), even if this is still incubating feature.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, this does not work for me. `project.getTasks()` has only one task `sample`, so I get the error *Cannot invoke method dependsOn() on null object*

Comment: very strange: you applied plugin 'java' so your project should have all tasks exposed by java plugin.. can you try to apply first 'java' plugin, and then your SamplePlugin ? I guess the order matters , here

Comment: I confirm my previous comment: you need to apply first 'java' plugin and then your sampleplugin, so that when your plugin is "executed" (apply method invoqued), the Java plugin has already been configured and Java related tasks declared on your project instance.

Comment: Thank you very much. Changing the order of the plugin applications worked.

Comment: glad it helped :) I think you should now accept one of the two answers provided, which are both valid and solved your initial issue.

Comment: Thank you. I hate choosing one answer, when both of the solutions are good. I did like **lu.koerfer** solution of using the `pluginManager.withPlugin` call to make this work irrespective of application of the plugins.

Answer (score 3):

The methods `mustRunAfter` and `shouldRunAfter` only define execution order, not causality. That means that they won't cause a task to be executed. But **if** both tasks are executed, the specified order will be taken into account.

To specify a task dependency, use `dependsOn` or `finalizedBy`:

```
project.pluginManager.withPlugin('java') {
    project.tasks.getByName('check').finalizedBy('sample');
}
```

This would cause `sample` to run everytime `check` runs **and** it ensures that it runs after `check`.

Comment: Thank you. I think this should be `project` i.e. without the **s**, because with the **s** I get an exception. Anyway, at this point `project.tasks` seems to have just one task `sample`, so this errors out with *Task with name 'check' not found in root project 'tempTest'.* I'd be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: see my last comment on the other answer : you need to apply plugins in the correct order:  first Java, then your SamplePlugin.

Comment: You should **never** define requirements on the order in which plugins must be applied. Instead, use the `PluginManager` and its `withPlugin` method to ensure a specific plugin has been applied.

Comment: Thank you. Using the `pluginManager` is a good idea to ensure this does not depend on the order of plugin application. I wish if this solution could be merged with the solution provided by **M.Ricciuti** above.